# Let $\{x_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ be a sequence. Suppose it is true that $x_n \to \infty$. Prove that the sequence $1/x_n$ converges to 0.

Tags: abstract-algebra

> Let $\{x_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ be a sequence. Suppose it is true that $x_n \to \infty$. Write a proof that the sequence $1/x_n$ converges to $0$.

We are supposed to make use of the definition of convergence: (∀ε > 0)(∃N ∈ N)(∀n ∈ N)[n ≥ N =⇒ |xn − L| < ε], as well as the definition of divergence: (∀M > 0)(∃N ∈ N)(∀n ∈ N)[n ≥ N =⇒ xn > M]. (I am assuming I start out with the divergence definition)

Proof: Let M>0. Choose N∈N such that for all n∈N, if n >= N, then xn>M. I am not sure where to go from here or how to combine the convergence and divergence definitions.

Comment: Please learn mathjax..

Comment: What he said:  http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Answer (score 1):

Read the definition of convergence of $\{ y_n\}$ to $y$:

> $\forall \epsilon > 0 \ \exists N \in \mathbb{N} \ \forall n > N , |y_n-y| < \epsilon$

So what are you supposed to do? Well, *you fix an $\epsilon$ and find a corresponding $N$*. That's all.

So fix an $\epsilon > 0$. It is given that $x_n$ is a divergent sequence. Here, use the definition of divergence:

$$
\forall M > 0 \ \exists N \in \mathbb{N} \ \forall n \geq N , |x_n| > M
$$

Therefore, take $M = \frac{1}{\epsilon}$. The definition of divergence says that there is an $N$ such that $n \geq N \implies |x_n| > \frac{1}{\epsilon} \implies \frac{1}{|x_n|} < \epsilon \implies |\frac{1}{x_n} - 0| < \epsilon$.

Therefore, we picked an $\epsilon > 0$, and found an $N$ such that $|\frac{1}{x_n} - 0|< \epsilon$ whenever $n > N$. This completes the proof, i.e. $x_n \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$.

Answer (score 0):

Since $x_n \to \infty$, you can always find an $n$ such that $x_n\geq k>0$. From this, you can build a subsequence $x_{n_k}$ with $x_{n_k} \geq k$ and so;

$$\frac{1}{x_{n_k}} \leq\frac{1}{k} \to 0$$

Now just recall that $x_{n_k}, x_n$ have the same limit.